# Concept of creating or attaching database to the instance of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server database which I can attach manually using SSMS and application works fine after this. I want to make the process automatic, i.e do not want my clients to use SSMS to attach database, but I want my application to do it at first time run or during installation.

But I have no idea at all how to do it. Many people suggested code snippets but I do not know where to put them.

I have seen a concept of SQLDMO but could not find over google how to make and use them in vb.net.

Could any body give me some help on it?

After getting hint, I tried following code in vb.net

```
Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Server=(local);Data Source=;Integrated Security=SSPI")
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("", conn)

    cmd.CommandText = "CREATE DATABASE MyDBTest ON ( FILENAME = 'D:\dbSQLTest.mdf' ), ( FILENAME = 'D:\dbSQLTest_log.ldf' ) FOR ATTACH"

    conn.Open()

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    cmd.Dispose()
    conn.Dispose()
```

When executed, it returns error
Unable to open the physical file "D:.Net Programs\AttachDBProg\AttachDBProg\dbSQLTest.mdf". Operating system error 5: "5(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105)".
Please help.
Thanks

Comment: As of SQL Server 2005 (you didn't mention which **version** you use.....) you should look at [SMO (SQL Management Objects)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13755/SMO-Manage-your-SQL-Server) instead of SQL-DMO which is deprecated (don't use it anymore!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`FOR ATTACH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx) one you have connected to the server for the 1st time by executing:

`CREATE DATABASE XXX ON ( FILENAME = N'blah.mdf' ), ( FILENAME = N'blah.ldf' ) FOR ATTACH;`

Comment: Thanks! what confuses me is, I already have a database, say dbTest so where does that name come and where do I write your given code.  vb.net does not recoginze it. How to call it in vb.net

Comment: So you want to replace the files of an existing database? You could; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345483.aspx or simpler would be to ship a .bak backup and restore with overwrite